Optimize Timing of Inject Function AnyLogic
I need help setting up an optimization experiment in AnyLogic. My model includes two agents, Agent1 and Agent2, which go through processing steps and then enter an assembler together. I want to optimize the timing of Agent1’s creation to maximize the assembly rate, which is controlled by the variable arrival of Agent2.
Current Setup
•   Agent2’s arrival is variable and defined by an external table, meaning its arrival sequence is not consistent.
•   Agent1 needs to be injected dynamically based on Agent2’s arrival, ensuring that Agent1 is created just in time to enter the assembler with Agent2, but without creating unnecessary instances.

Objective
In the optimization experiment, I want to:
•   Optimize the timing for injecting each instance of Agent1 to meet Agent2’s demand at the assembler.
•   Maximize the assembly rate supported by Agent2’s arrival schedule, without over-producing Agent1.

Is there a way to set up the optimization so that Agent1’s injections align dynamically with each instance of Agent2? Ideally, I’d like to avoid creating surplus instances of Agent1 while ensuring assembly happens as frequently as Agent2 allows.
Agent 1 has a fixed processing duration of 50 days, so ideally the experiment would run once, record when Agent2 enters a queue, calculate the optimal injection time as the enter date - 50, schedule inject at these times, then rerun
Thanks in advance for any insights on how to structure this experiment!

Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

sequencing problems are not well resolved by optimization algorithms.
But if agent 2 arrival is deterministic then yes you can optimize the arrival of agent1, in which you would have 1 parameter for each agent1, which would be how much time to wait to inject it since the beginning of the simulation.
But doing this will be useless for any real-life purpose.
Sequencial problems are more suitable for reinforcement learning instead of optimization.

On the source block for Agent2 you can just add a sourceAgent1.inject() and inject Agent1 at exactly the same time. And after Agent2 source you input an infinite capacity delay of 50 days.
For example, if there would be an Agent2 arriving at 105, it should now arrive at 55 and inject an Agent1, and be delayed until 105. Of course, this is assuming you somehow know 50 days in advance that Agent2 will be coming.
Another way would be to have a buffer of Agent1 available waiting for Agent2 and some metrics as objective function (Agent2 queue time, or % of Agent2 waiting for Agent1 for example) and  then you optimize t he buffer of Agent1.
